# how to launch chrome with an authenticated proxy and authenticate them with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, puppeteer

so launching a chrome instance using these flags ;

```
`chrome --remote-debugging-port=${port}   --user-data-dir="C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data  --proxy-server=http://host:port`
```

and the proxy is an private one which have username and password to be able to be used ,

and i tried connecting a puppeteer instance into that chrome and authenticate using puppeteer but that seems don't work

```
const browserURL = `http://127.0.0.1:9222`;
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL, defaultViewport : null });
const page = await browser.newPage();
let username = "username"
let password = "password"
await page.authenticate({
  username: username,
  password: password,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use HTTP headers instead of `page.authenticate`:

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Proxy-Authorization': 'username:password',
});
```

Refer to your proxies documentation on what the name of the headers is, and how to properly encode it.

Comment: i think proxy-authorization send a base64 header , thank you i will try it